# Is product of subgaussian and indicator random variable subgaussian?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be such that $X - \mathbb{E}[X]$ is a subgaussian random variable and $Y$ a random variable supported on $\{0,1\}$ (not necessarily independent from $X$). Is $XY - \mathbb{E}[XY]$ subgaussian as well?

Comment: $$\mathbb P(|XY|>t)=\mathbb P(|X|>t,Y=1)\leq \mathbb P(|X|>t).$$

Comment: @NCh I think this doesn't quite solve it. For this argument to imply the desired result  we would need both $X$ and $XY$ to be centered. This need not be the case (unless they're uncorrelated).

Comment: If $X$ is subgaussian then $X+c$ is subgaussian too.